# Does .net core run on ARM Cortex-A7?

Tags: linux, .net-core, arm

I created a small console app for testing it with an ARM Cortex-A7 device.
I tried to use couple of runtimes

- linux-arm
- linux-arm64
- linux-musle-arm
- linux-musle-arm64

but without success. If I'm using a 32bit runtime, the executable will not found. If I'm using a 64bit runtime, it fails with the following output:

> root@MC100:~# /root/publish/openwrttest /root/publish/openwrttest:
> line 1: can't open @▒@8: no such file /root/publish/openwrttest: line
> 1:ELF▒: not found /root/publish/openwrttest: line 2:
> @!@@@0ppp1▒1▒▒▒▒▒▒8 T
> 8▒8▒8▒p▒▒▒DDP▒td▒▒Q▒td▒▒▒▒R▒td▒▒▒▒▒▒H/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1GNUGNU▒▒׽S▒Ym▒
> a▒x|▒#p]| ▒ ▒ ▒▒▒▒▒: not found /root/publish/openwrttest: PuTTYline 2:
> L▒▒: not found /root/publish/openwrttest: line 4: syntax error:
> unterminated quoted string

So my question is, does it work with this cpu? Does anyone have already expirence with that or any idea where is my mistake?

**UPDATE**
LDD trace gives the following info:

> root@MC100:~# ldd /root/publish/openwrttest
> /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76ee0000)
> libpthread.so.0 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76ee0000)
> libdl.so.2 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76ee0000)
> libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x76dc2000)
> libm.so.6 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76ee0000)
> libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x76da7000)
> libc.so.6 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76ee0000) Error loading shared library ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
> (needed by /root/publish/openwrttest)

Comment: Would demonstrating that .NET SDK 7.0 and applications built using it are working on a Cortex-A7-based Linux system qualify as an answer ? if not, could you provide the exact link to the .NET SDK for arm32 you are trying to use ?

Comment: Since openwrt is musl libc-based, this is unlikely that `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` would be present on your system: the dynamic linker would be `/lib/ld-musl-armhf.so.1`, and not `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3`. This seems like you are trying to execute a glibc implementation of .NET on a musl-based system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, .NET Core 3.0 works on a ARM Cortex-A7 - Tested on a quad Cortex-A7 nanopi2-m1 running Armbian buster -  See Microsoft installation instructions [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-3.0.103-linux-arm32-binaries).

```
wget https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/4a44d4d2-19c1-485a-8b58-fa06805cddcf/cc805a1ebd9d72099309dcd46492d36f/dotnet-sdk-3.0.103-linux-arm.tar.gz
mkdir -p $HOME/dotnet && tar zxf dotnet-sdk-3.0.103-linux-arm.tar.gz -C $HOME/dotnet
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet


# Verify dotnet is working.
dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.103
 Commit:    b7ef045669

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     debian
 OS Version:  10
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         debian.10-arm
 Base Path:   /home/user/dotnet/sdk/3.0.103/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.3
  Commit:  c03f2fe626

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.0.103 [/home/user/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.3 [/home/user/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.3 [/home/user/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

# Create HelloWorld application.
dotnet new console -o HelloWorld

cd HelloWorld/
dotnet run
Hello, World!
```

Please note that,  according to Microsoft, .NET Core 3.0 is now obsolete and not supported anymore: *This release has reached end of life, meaning it is no longer supported. We recommend moving to a supported release, such as .NET 7.0*.

This having been said, .NET 7.0 works perfectly fine too on a Cortex-A7 using for example dotnet-sdk-7.0.101-linux-musl-arm (You can download it from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0)).

Tested this time on the same quad Cortex-A7 nanopi2-m1 running Alpine Linux 3.17.0 - See Microsoft installation instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual).

Procedure:

```
wget https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/bde0b4e5-2b2c-4046-a74f-6618bfa8ab8a/3170cd4312552c2eba2a0de3acd85337/dotnet-sdk-7.0.101-linux-musl-arm.tar.gz
mkdir -p $HOME/dotnet && tar zxf dotnet-sdk-7.0.101-linux-musl-arm.tar.gz -C $HOME/dotnet
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet

# Verify dotnet is working.  
dotnet

Usage: dotnet [options]
Usage: dotnet [path-to-application]

Options:
  -h|--help         Display help.
  --info            Display .NET information.
  --list-sdks       Display the installed SDKs.
  --list-runtimes   Display the installed runtimes.

path-to-application:
  The path to an application .dll file to execute.
  
# Create HelloWorld application.
dotnet new console -o HelloWorld  -f net7.0

cd HelloWorld/
dotnet run
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Thank you @Frant! My first mistake was, that dotnet was not installed. Very bad mistake! But after installing, I will get the following exception

##
root@MC100:~# dotnet
Error relocating /root/dotnet/dotnet: _ZNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /root/dotnet/dotnet: __time64: symbol not found
Error relocating /root/dotnet/dotnet: __gmtime64: symbol not found
Error relocating /root/dotnet/dotnet: __fstat_time64: symbol not found
Error relocating /root/dotnet/dotnet: __dlsym_time64: symbol not found
...

Comment: It looks like 'dotnet' will try to use a 64bit and not 32bit?!

Comment: same with 'dotnet-runtime-7.0.1-linux-musl-arm.tar.gz'

Comment: Looks like, the are some changes in the musl library since september '21 
https://forum.openwrt.org/t/openssl-util-1-1-1l-1-error-relocating-usr-lib-libssl-so-1-1-time64-symbol-not-found/108861/2

Comment: It seems a function dealing with 64 bits time values may be missing. By the way, if you think I answered you question - I think I did: .NET works on a Cortex-A7 - I would appreciate you accepting it. No obligation to do this though.

Comment: Absolutely! Sorry that I has not reacted.